# Do all react-native '.h' modules have to be prepended with 'React/'?

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, react-native-ios

Setup:

- react-native v0.41.2
- react-native-cli v2.0.1
- xcode v8.2.1
- node v6.9.5

---

I started using RN v0.41.2 and found that [v0.40 introduced a namespace breaking change](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/wiki/Breaking-Changes#040) stating that all react imports should be prepended with `React/`.

But the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html#ios-calendar-module-example) shows otherwise.

So, is doing this the only thing that I have to do:

```
// RNLib.h

#import "RCTBridgeModule.h"

@interface RNLib : NSObject <RCTBridgeModule>

@end
```

to

```
// RNLib.h

#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>

@interface RNLib : NSObject <RCTBridgeModule>

@end
```

Or do I have to do it for my imports as well:

```
// RNLib.m

#import "RNLib.h"

@implementation RNLib

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(helloWorld:(NSString *)world)
{
  return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"hello %@", world];
}

@end
```

to

```
// RNLib.m

#import <React/RNLib.h>

@implementation RNLib

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(helloWorld:(NSString *)world)
{
  return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"hello %@", world];
}

@end
```

I'm currently unable to create a library and link it correctly (I've tried multiple things).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// somthing.m
#import "something.h"
```

This above line refers to something.h file which is present in same directory of the implementation file.

Only Modules from the React should be prepended with `"React/RCTWhatever.h"`.

This has effective change in Header Search Paths of Xcode when you are linking the Native Libraries.

Thanks